# Getting run time error when adding constraints

Tags: swift, constraints, view

I'm trying to center an image to a view but I'm getting error..this is my code:

```
let markerimage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_new_mark_icon")

    let size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)

    var newimage = imageWithImage(image: markerimage, scaledToSize: size)

    var imageview = UIImageView(image: newimage)

    self.view.addSubview(imageview)


    let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageview, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageview, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    imageview.addConstraint(xConstraint)
    imageview.addConstraint(yConstraint)
```

and my error is

```
2016-12-22 16:29:11.305417 Googlemappractice[21426:362773] [LayoutConstraints] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000285f00 UIImageView:0x7ff772f15560.centerX == UIView:0x7ff772c0bd30.centerX   (inactive)>
    When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout)
```

Comment: You need to add those constraints to self.view, not image view. Also, make sure you've turned off the autoresize flag (you probably have but I didn't see that code).

Comment: Since iOS8, its been possible to just activate the constraints instead of adding them to views.  Set `xConstraint.isActive = true` and `yConstraint.isActive = true`.

Answer (score 1):

The constraints need to be added to the earliest common ancestor of the two views affected by the constraint.  In this case, `self.view` is earlier in the hierarchy so the constraints should be added to it instead of to `imageview`.

Since iOS 8, there is an easier way.  Once you've added your view to the view hierarchy (with `addSubview`), you can activate the constraints instead of adding them to views.

You can do this by setting the `isActive` property to true:

```
xConstraint.isActive = true
yConstraint.isActive = true
```

or by using the `activate` class function of `NSLayoutConstraint` to active multiple constraints:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([xConstraint, yConstraint])
```

---

As mentioned by @dfd in the comments, you should also set this flag:

```
imageview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

This tells iOS to not create constraints for `imageview` based upon its frame.  If you don't do this, you'll end up with conflicting constraints.

You are going to need width and height constraints for your `imageview` as well, because you've only specified its position so far.

Comment: Thanks @vacawama. I set my constraints a bit differently (most in arrays, all with more "Swifty" syntax) and never thought to set isActive to true. I learn something new every day here on SO and today's lesson is now complete!